# Proxmox System freezes after 30-40 minutes running, no containers/VMs running

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, proxmox

I am having some problems with a new-to-me used Xeon E3-1225 server I'm trying to turn into home server.

Currently, I have it setup with Proxmox installed, two 1TB hard drives (different makes/models) in a RAID1 ZFS pool for the base operating system and ideally some VMs. I have two 4 TB HDDs that I was going to use for mass storage, in a ZFS RAID1 also, but currently just hold some back up data.

At the moment, I just have Proxmox installed, no VMs or containers running beyond the default setup. I was moving data from the 4 TB HDD to the newly made ZFS pool on the 1TB disks (root home directory), but in doing so Proxmox repeatedly became unresponsive. I've tried 3 times, and each time the system drops the network connection and hangs and I'm not sure what's happening anymore.

```
Feb  2 20:40:21 theHive kernel: [  356.464000] EXT4-fs (sda1): recovery complete
Feb  2 20:40:21 theHive kernel: [  356.482202] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Feb  2 20:44:33 theHive kernel: [  608.563501] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is Down
Feb  2 20:44:33 theHive kernel: [  608.563522] vmbr0: port 1(enp2s0) entered disabled state
Feb  2 20:44:34 theHive kernel: [  610.230917] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
Feb  2 20:44:34 theHive kernel: [  610.230931] vmbr0: port 1(enp2s0) entered blocking state
Feb  2 20:44:34 theHive kernel: [  610.230933] vmbr0: port 1(enp2s0) entered forwarding state
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840254] WARNING: CPU: 4 PID: 0 at kernel/sched/core.c:4014 schedule_idle+0x34/0x40
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840270] Modules linked in: ebtable_filter ebtables ip_set ip6table_raw iptable_raw ip6table_filter ip6_tables iptable_filter bpfilter softdog nfnetlink_log nfnetlink intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm snd_hda_codec_hdmi irqbypass i915 snd_hda_codec_realtek crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul snd_hda_codec_generic ghash_clmulni_intel ledtrig_audio aesni_intel drm_kms_helper aes_x86_64 drm snd_hda_intel crypto_simd snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core cryptd i2c_algo_bit snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_timer glue_helper snd fb_sys_fops syscopyarea intel_cstate soundcore mei_hdcp sysfillrect mei_me intel_rapl_perf mei sysimgblt ie31200_edac pcspkr mac_hid vhost_net vhost tap ib_iser rdma_cm iw_cm ib_cm ib_core sunrpc iscsi_tcp libiscsi_tcp libiscsi scsi_transport_iscsi ip_tables x_tables autofs4 zfs(PO) zunicode(PO) zlua(PO) zavl(PO) icp(PO) zcommon(PO) znvpair(PO) spl(O) btrfs xor zstd_compress raid6_pq libcrc32c ahci i2c_i801 libahci lpc_ich r8169
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840292]  realtek video
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840304] CPU: 4 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/4 Tainted: P           O      5.3.10-1-pve #1
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840306] Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. Z87M-D3H/Z87M-D3H, BIOS F4 04/16/2013
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840308] RIP: 0010:schedule_idle+0x34/0x40
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840310] Code: 25 c0 6b 01 00 48 8b 40 10 48 89 e5 48 85 c0 75 19 31 ff e8 9e f6 ff ff 65 48 8b 04 25 c0 6b 01 00 48 8b 00 a8 08 75 e9 5d c3 <0f> 0b eb e3 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 48 89 e5 e8
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840312] RSP: 0018:ffffb435800abec0 EFLAGS: 00010206
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840314] RAX: 0000000000001000 RBX: ffff989e2cf1dc00 RCX: 0000000000000000
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840316] RDX: 00000476777ed6de RSI: ffff989e2f11e040 RDI: 0000000000000004
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840317] RBP: ffffb435800abec0 R08: 0000000000000002 R09: 0000000000000006
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840318] R10: 00000e4b10e536cb R11: ffff989e2f1294c4 R12: ffffffff86e4a840
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840320] R13: ffff989e2f135320 R14: ffffffff86d588e0 R15: 0000000000000005
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840321] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff989e2f100000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840323] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840324] CR2: 000055ca19aa1fb0 CR3: 00000001e7a0a005 CR4: 00000000001606e0
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840326] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840327] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840328] Call Trace:
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840333]  do_idle+0x16b/0x270
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840335]  cpu_startup_entry+0x1d/0x20
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840338]  start_secondary+0x167/0x1c0
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840341]  secondary_startup_64+0xa4/0xb0
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840343] ---[ end trace 51b959059837262e ]---
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840345] bad: scheduling from the idle thread!
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840346] CPU: 4 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/4 Tainted: P        W  O      5.3.10-1-pve #1
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840348] Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. Z87M-D3H/Z87M-D3H, BIOS F4 04/16/2013
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840349] Call Trace:
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840351]  dump_stack+0x63/0x8a
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840353]  dequeue_task_idle+0x2c/0x40
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840356]  dequeue_task+0xd7/0x2d0
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840358]  ? invalid_op+0x1e/0x30
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840359]  deactivate_task+0x3a/0x40
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840361]  __schedule+0x118/0x660
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840363]  schedule_idle+0x22/0x40
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840364]  do_idle+0x16b/0x270
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840366]  cpu_startup_entry+0x1d/0x20
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840368]  start_secondary+0x167/0x1c0
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840369]  secondary_startup_64+0xa4/0xb0
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840822] bad: scheduling from the idle thread!
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840835] CPU: 4 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/4 Tainted: P        W  O      5.3.10-1-pve #1
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840838] Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. Z87M-D3H/Z87M-D3H, BIOS F4 04/16/2013
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840840] Call Trace:
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840851]  dump_stack+0x63/0x8a
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840853]  dequeue_task_idle+0x2c/0x40
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840855]  dequeue_task+0xd7/0x2d0
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840858]  ? sched_clock+0x9/0x10
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840861]  deactivate_task+0x3a/0x40
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840862]  __schedule+0x118/0x660
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840864]  schedule_idle+0x22/0x40
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840866]  do_idle+0x16b/0x270
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840868]  cpu_startup_entry+0x1d/0x20
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840869]  start_secondary+0x167/0x1c0
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840871]  secondary_startup_64+0xa4/0xb0
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840938] bad: scheduling from the idle thread!
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840940] CPU: 4 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/4 Tainted: P        W  O      5.3.10-1-pve #1
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840943] Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. Z87M-D3H/Z87M-D3H, BIOS F4 04/16/2013
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840944] Call Trace:
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840946]  dump_stack+0x63/0x8a
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840948]  dequeue_task_idle+0x2c/0x40
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840950]  dequeue_task+0xd7/0x2d0
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840952]  ? sched_clock+0x9/0x10
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840953]  deactivate_task+0x3a/0x40
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840955]  __schedule+0x118/0x660
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840957]  schedule_idle+0x22/0x40
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840959]  do_idle+0x16b/0x270
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840960]  cpu_startup_entry+0x1d/0x20
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840962]  start_secondary+0x167/0x1c0
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.840964]  secondary_startup_64+0xa4/0xb0
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.843707] bad: scheduling from the idle thread!
Feb  2 21:56:11 theHive kernel: [ 4906.843731] CPU: 4 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/4 Tainted: P        W  O      5.3.10-1-pve #1
```

More recently, I tried doing the data backup to an external drive using a Linux Mint Live CD, and have not run into system crashing, so I don't believe it to be hardware related, but likely a bad setup/practice on my part.

Below is the kernel log after boot up, where errors started happening that I'm not entirely sure what's going on.

I truncated the kernel log, but the log is filled with the repeated part indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

I took a guess that it was a Motherboard problem compatibility problem with Proxmox/virtualization and the firmware.

I did a firmware update on the Motherboard and it seems to have fixed it.

Good luck to those finding this in the future.